# Improper IDFA usage, Apps contains IDFA but app is not respecting the Limit Ad Tracking settings in iOS

Tags: ios

Please see attached all frameworks I have referenced in my project. Still I get this Limit Ad track settings failed validation error. Could someone please suggest me which framework might be responsible or what may I need to do. I am just stuck and have been struggling for last 1 days :( . Thanks for your help!

I have 
Tapjoy
facebook
adsupport
libFlurry_4.4..0.a
iad
uikit
frameworks in my code. If I remove ADsupport, mygame fails with message that it needs for running on ios 6.0, although I am targeting for ios 7.0 as deployment target. Any help is greatly appreciated. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Apple changed their IDFA scanning procedures recently. Not only do you have to check the appropriate checkboxes after you click on the "prepare for upload", but your code (or any other third party library that you have must use IDFA by using the class directly.

> Someone suggested to do this:
>
> "you can do that by replacing direct refs to ASIdentifierManager with NSClassFromString(@"ASIdentifierManager")"

DO NOT load this class using this approach! New scanning procedure will look specifically for this and if it is found instead of direct references - Apple seems to assume that there is some strange usage of the tracking identifier. I can't say I disagree with that decision.

It may not be easy to find exactly which library is at fault. Latest AdMob SDK for example is using the class directly and is NOT the source of a problem.

**One way you can find out which library is the source of the problem is to remove AdSupport.Framework from your project and see which libraries fail to link. Those libraries are NOT the problem. See if you have other advertising libraries that do not require you to include AdSupport.Framework - those are most likely the culprit.**

It sounds a bit counter intuitive, but the direct referencing is not the problem, dynamic (weak) loading of that class is.

My guess is that Tapjoy is the culprit since I did use the latest Flury and iAd without issues.

Hope this helps you - we were pulling our hair out for a few days before we figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

grep for ASIdenfierManager on the folder of your project

in that way I found ASIdenfierManager in the libGoogleConversionTracking library